# how to put state array equal to another array using use State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using useState hook to store an array and initially I am setting it to an empty array. when data is fetched. I am using setState to change it but its not working.
thanks in advance

```
const ShipmentArrival = ({
  isAuthenticated,
  productLoading,
  user,
  products,
  loadProducts,
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    loadProducts();
  }, [loadProducts]);

  const [newProducts, setNewProducts] = useState([]);

  if (!productLoading) {
    setNewProducts(products);
    console.log(products);
    for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      console.log(newProducts);
      // this log shows that the array is empty
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is better to handle this kind of senarios in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!productLoading){
    setNewProducts([...newProducts , products]);
    console.log('Products => ' , newProducts)
  }
}, [productLoading])
```

Comment: still not working, array is empty!!

Comment: change the dependency inside useEffect to products and also check if products.length > 0 => if(products.length > 0){ ...before code }

Comment: and also console.log the products inside useEffect to make sure if products change.

Comment: tried both of those already, still nothing. Even console logged the products to check and it does contains data

Comment: what is the type of products you get from props is it an array?

Comment: yes its an array of objects

Comment: so try setting state like this => setNewProducts([...newProducts , ...products]);

Comment: still nothing!!

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: No there are no errors but since the newProducts array is empty I cant use It. I tried copying products to a simple array( not state array) that works fine but I need State variable.

Comment: I was using an input which was reading the value from the newProducts that was the issue. I had a check on the return but I guess that was for the data coming from state props! thanks for the help @Paiman Rasoli